# Plotting amplitude vs frequency in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I want to plot an amplitude vs frequency with this formula:
[image]

By using this data:

[image]

So it should look like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, I don´t manage it to plot this. Could someone help please ?

Comment: Could you please make the input data a $ 9\times 2 $ list?

Comment: xx = {4.19, 3.93, 3.7, 3.49, 3.31, 3.31, 3.14, 2.99, 1.75};
yy = {0.18, 0.35, 0.45, 1.06, 1.13, 0.77, 0.57, 0.34, 0.14};

Comment: Thi forum is devoted to WolframMathematica (shorter Mathematica). There is no need to stress Mathematica in the title.

Comment: The size of your data which equals 9 is too small for reliable conclusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only meant as an answer to a question in one of the comments about how to reverse the x-axis that I couldn't fit into a comment easily.

You can add the option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}` to the plot in order to reverse the x-axis. Unfortunately, this means that the data points themselves will not show up. Probably the easiest solution is to show the points in a separate `ListPlot` and reverse the x-axis there as well:

```
Show[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[model /. fittedparameters],
  {\[Omega], 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}
  ],
 ListPlot[
  data,
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Fitted model with reversed x-axis.]

Comment: Looks great, thank you!

Comment: No problem, but you can only accept one of the answers, and I think it should go to Αλέξανδρος-Ζεγγ as they answered the main question. My "answer" was just meant to slightly build upon their answer.

Comment: So it cannot work with `Epilog`?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ IMO, the way MMA reverses the axes is a bit hack-y. It basically takes the negative of everything so that Epilog points are no longer in the place you would expect them. To reverse the x-axis using your method, I would add `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}` to the list of options, and then inside the Epilog I would change `Point[data]` to `Point[data.{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}}]`.

Comment: @MassDefect Inspiring, thx very much!

Answer (score 4):

The input data is arranged as

```
data = {{4.19, 3.93, 3.7, 3.49, 3.31, 3.31, 3.14, 2.99, 1.75}, {0.18, 0.35, 0.45, 1.06, 1.13, 0.77, 0.57, 0.34, 0.14}}\[Transpose];
```

Then fit a nonlinear model

```
model = (a ω^2) / Sqrt[(ω^2 - ωe^2)^2 + 4 γ^2 ωe^2];
fittedparameters = FindFit[data, model, {a, ωe, γ}, ω]
```

which returns

```
{a -> 0.0895665, ωe -> 3.394, γ -> 0.123515}
```

So finally plot the result

```
Plot[Evaluate[model /. fittedparameters], {ω, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Blue, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.015], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, looks great!!!

Comment: I think the plot should converge towards 0, not starting at 0. How could we mirror the x-axis ?

Comment: @Tom Could please rephrase your statement, but I could really not quite catch you.

Comment: I mean, how could we realize to start x-axis at 5 going down to 0 from left to right, so the graph would decay towards 0.. so just rotate x-axis 180°

Comment: @Tom Do you mean to make the ticks on the $ x $-axis go from large to small?

Comment: right. sorry for stupid questions! :)

Comment: @Tom Sorry, but I do not have a quick answer to this question.

Comment: no problem, you helped me enough! thank you very much!!!